# Getting the 1d counts separately from a histogram2d

Tags: python, numpy

I have two 1d data and I used `histogram2d` to get the counts at each grid using 10 bins

```
x1 = np.random.normal(5,5,340)
y1 = np.random.normal(5,5,340)

x1y1, edgex1, edgey1 = np.histogram2d(x=x1,y=y1, bins=10)
x1y1
```

Output:

```
array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  3.,  3.,  2.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  2.,  2.,  3.,  8.,  2.,  1.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 2.,  1.,  3.,  8., 13., 11., 14.,  3.,  2.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  3.,  6., 10.,  9., 11., 12., 14.,  3.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  3.,  6., 11., 22., 13., 12.,  5.,  2.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  4.,  9., 14., 17., 11.,  4.,  2.,  2.],
       [ 1.,  0.,  3.,  2.,  7., 10.,  4.,  3.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  3.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  2.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]])
```

However, I would like to know the number of x1 and y1 points separately in each of the grids such that when they are summed up, they are equal to the points in the output array(x1y1).

Also I don't know if it's possible to get these individual counts of x1 and y1 to be the same size of the matrix x1y1. If, it is possible, I would like to know how.

Any idea is welcomed and thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If I get it right then you would like to have the **boundary distributions**. Taking the figures of your matrix this can achieved with:

```
sum_along_vertical = np.sum(x1y1, axis=0)
sum_along_vertical

array([ 4.,  8., 25., 43., 74., 75., 60., 34., 13.,  4.])
```

and

```
sum_along_horizontal = np.sum(x1y1, axis=1)
sum_along_horizontal

array([ 9., 19., 58., 69., 75., 64., 31., 12.,  2.,  1.])
```

You might them **blow up to matrix format** with

```
iy = np.ones(sum_along_horizontal.shape[0])
X1 = np.outer(iy,sum_along_vertical)    
X1

array([[ 4.,  8., 25., 43., 74., 75., 60., 34., 13.,  4.],
       [ 4.,  8., 25., 43., 74., 75., 60., 34., 13.,  4.],
       [ 4.,  8., 25., 43., 74., 75., 60., 34., 13.,  4.],
       [ 4.,  8., 25., 43., 74., 75., 60., 34., 13.,  4.],
       [ 4.,  8., 25., 43., 74., 75., 60., 34., 13.,  4.],
       [ 4.,  8., 25., 43., 74., 75., 60., 34., 13.,  4.],
       [ 4.,  8., 25., 43., 74., 75., 60., 34., 13.,  4.],
       [ 4.,  8., 25., 43., 74., 75., 60., 34., 13.,  4.],
       [ 4.,  8., 25., 43., 74., 75., 60., 34., 13.,  4.],
       [ 4.,  8., 25., 43., 74., 75., 60., 34., 13.,  4.]])
```

and

```
ix = np.ones(sum_along_vertical.shape[0])
Y1 = np.outer(sum_along_horizontal,ix)    
Y1

array([[ 9.,  9.,  9.,  9.,  9.,  9.,  9.,  9.,  9.,  9.],
       [19., 19., 19., 19., 19., 19., 19., 19., 19., 19.],
       [58., 58., 58., 58., 58., 58., 58., 58., 58., 58.],
       [69., 69., 69., 69., 69., 69., 69., 69., 69., 69.],
       [75., 75., 75., 75., 75., 75., 75., 75., 75., 75.],
       [64., 64., 64., 64., 64., 64., 64., 64., 64., 64.],
       [31., 31., 31., 31., 31., 31., 31., 31., 31., 31.],
       [12., 12., 12., 12., 12., 12., 12., 12., 12., 12.],
       [ 2.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  2.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.]])
```

Comment: Yes, something like that. But the issue is for eg, the output value is 13 (row 3, col 5), I want to know the count of x1 and y1 such they both equal 13 in the output. Its more like knowing the contribution of x1 and y1.